# How can display/retrieve my database data in reactive form array in angular 12

Tags: angular

Hi i have created a form array and sent data to database successfully in angular 12 but i don't know  how can retrieve/display that data from data base in same form array, which should be editable ,here i m using modal for data source for explaining ,can any one help me out it is very importent for me, thanks in advance  here my stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xuamdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
<div class="container border">
  <form [formGroup]="members">
    <ng-container formArrayName="member" *ngFor="let o of member.controls; let i = index">
      <h2>Member {{ i + 1 }}</h2>
      <div [formGroupName]="i" class="border my-2">
        <div class="form-group row py-2">
          <label for="" class="col-form-label col-sm-2 ms-1">1.Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4 mx-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="memberName"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row py-2">
          <label for="" class="col-form-label col-sm-2 ms-1" >2. Relation With Applicant</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4 mx-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="relation"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row py-2">
          <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 ms-1">3.PAN</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4 mx-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="pan" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row py-2">
          <label class="col-form-lable col-sm-2 ms-1" >4. Aadhar(uid) Number</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4 mx-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="aadhar"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row py-2">
          <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-lable ms-1" >5. Residential/Registered Address</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9 mx-2">
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" formControlName="address" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-100 text-end">
          <button type="button"class="btn btn-danger my-2 text-center float-right" (click)="removeMembers(i)" >
            <i class="fa fa-trash">&nbsp;Remove</i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </form>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-2 text-center" (click)="addMembers()" > Add Member </button>
</div>
```

**ts**

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private database: DatabaseData) {}
  myData: any = [];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createMember();
    this.myData = this.database.member;
    console.log('database data', this.myData);
  }
  members!: FormGroup;
  createMember() {
    this.members = this.fb.group({
      member: this.fb.array([this.memberForm()]),
      mobile: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });
  }

  memberForm() {
    return this.fb.group({
      memberName: ['', Validators.required],
      relation: ['', Validators.required],
      pan: ['', Validators.required],
      aadhar: ['', Validators.required],
      address: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
  get member() {
    return this.members.get('member') as FormArray;
  }
  addMembers() {
    this.member.push(this.memberForm());
  }
  removeMembers(i: number) {
    this.member.removeAt(i);
  }
}
}
```

**database.ts**

```
export class DatabaseData {
  member: any = [
    {
      memberName: 'Manoj kumar sahni',
      aadhar: '123456789123',
      address: 'bhopal',
      pan: 'cteps0613l',
      relation: 'self',
    },
    {
      memberName: 'Manoj kumar sahni',
      aadhar: '123456789123',
      address: 'bhopal',
      pan: 'cteps0613l',
      relation: 'self',
    },
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: here is a link to a working version of what you are looking for

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hwzhc9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Based on your code it does not appear that you are using `FormArray` but rather `FormGroup`. it seems that you are using a `FormGroup` that has nested `FormGroups`. that's perfectly fine, just clarifying.

```
// this defined a FormGroup
members!: FormGroup;
```

The form `patchValue` and `setValue` offer a simple way to update a FormGroup.  you can read more about these two methods in the official docs [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setValue)

Using this you could update your the method that fetches data from the back end to update your members `formGroup` as follows

```
this.members.patchValue({
  memberName: 
})
```

you were pulling values from your datastore, but never populating the FormGroups.

NOTE: you were also creating a mobile `FormControl` that was outside the FromGroup. that seemed odd, so I moved it into the standard form. but feel free to move it as you need to.

Here is the updated code:

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private database: DatabaseData) {}
  myData: MemberInfo[] = [];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addMember();
    this.myData = this.database.member;
    // populate existing formGroup for a user or creat new form group if needed
    this.myData.forEach((memberDetails: MemberInfo, index: number) => {
      // add a new form Group each member in returned data if one does not already exist
      if (!this.members.controls[index]) {
        this.addMember();
      }
      // patch the FormGroup with the data from the server.
      this.members.controls[index].patchValue(memberDetails);
    });
    console.log('database data', this.myData);
  }
  memberForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    members: new FormArray([]),
  });

  get members(): FormArray {
    return this.memberForm.get(`members`) as FormArray;
  }

  /** renamed method to be more descriptive */
  getMemberForm() {
    return this.fb.group({
      memberName: ['', Validators.required],
      relation: ['', Validators.required],
      pan: ['', Validators.required],
      aadhar: ['', Validators.required],
      address: ['', Validators.required],
      mobile: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  getMember(i: number): FormGroup {
    return this.members.get(`${i}`) as FormGroup;
  }

  /** Add a new formGroup to existing formArray */
  addMember() {
    this.members.push(this.getMemberForm());
  }

  /** remove a member form group at the designated index */
  removeMember(i: number) {
    this.members.removeAt(i);
  }
}
```

additionally, your template HTML needed some adjustments. Angular requires that a `FormArray` be defined within a `[FormGroup]`. however you were referencing the formArray as the `FormGroup`

here are the relevant changes

```
<form [formGroup]="memberForm">
    <div formArrayName="members">
      <div *ngFor="let member of members.controls; index as i">
        <h2>Member {{ i + 1 }}</h2>
        <div [formGroupName]="i" class="border my-2">
```

based on my tests, the app.component creates as many formGroups for each member in your datastore, adding & removing controls manually also works.

This should be enough to get you going, but I would suggest reviewing the official documentation on this top.

good luck.

Comment: Thank you mr adward .can you implement it in stackblitz properly because some error showing in stackblitz console,and data still not displying in form and when i m clicking on add member then it is not adding more members,i m new on it so kindly help me on it    https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ijqbus?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: link has been updated at the top or response